# How to complete missing column in R with another column

Tags: r, merge

I want to merge two column to complete each other. Here are the example of the data I want to merge

```
Movie  |  Rating(New) | Rating (Old) |
A  ................A...................Nan
B  ................B...................Nan
C  ................NaN...................C
D ................NaN...................A
```

I want to Create new column name rating contain both of them

```
Movie  |  Rating(New) | Rating (Old) | Rating
A  ................A...................Nan................A
B  ................B...................Nan................B
C  ................NaN...................C................C
D ................NaN...................A................A
```

I tried this code

```
df$Rating <- paste(df$Rating(New),df$Rating(Old)
```

But the `A` in Rating have two which is "A " and " A". The code create a space on them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way

```
df <- read.csv(text="
A,B,C
1,1,NaN
2,2,NaN
3,NaN,3
4,NaN,1
", colClasses = rep("numeric", 3))
df$D <- dplyr::coalesce(df$A, df$B)
df
#   A   B   C D
# 1 1   1 NaN 1
# 2 2   2 NaN 2
# 3 3 NaN   3 3
# 4 4 NaN   1 4
```

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table` you can inser one coloumn's value to another:

```
dt <- fread(text="
A,B,C
1,1,NaN
2,2,NaN
3,NaN,3
4,NaN,1
")
dt[is.na(B), B:=C]
```

Here you update rows where `B` is `NA`, and set those `B` to the value in `C`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simpler solution:

```
df$v3 = ifelse(df$v1 == "NaN", df$v2, df$v1)
```

Comment: Not if it's a text or factor variable. Text `"NaN"` will return `FALSE` to `is.nan`.